# SSRS Error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'."

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a query that runs fine in Management Studio. I am trying to create a DataSet in SSRS using the query.

SSRS throws an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'

Unfortunately, this is not very helpful, and I cannot figure out what is causing the error. Here is the query, modified for SSRS:

```
declare STARDTZ as datetime2
declare LASTDTZ as datetime2

SET STARDTZ = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @STARTDT), 0)
SET LASTDTZ = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @LASTDT), 0)
;
with dates(dt) as (select STARDTZ union all select dateadd(day,1,dt) from dates where dt < LASTDTZ)

select 

Name
,SUM(IntervalMin) as Minutes
,DateBin

from 
(

select t.Name
,case when t.StartDT>=d.dt then t.StartDT else d.dt end as StartDT
,case when datediff(day,LastDT,dt)=0 then t.LastDT else dateadd(day,1,d.dt) end as LastDT 
,datediff(millisecond,case when t.StartDT>=d.dt then t.StartDT else d.dt end
,case when datediff(day,LastDT,dt)=0 then t.LastDT else dateadd(day,1,d.dt) end)/60000.0 as IntervalMin
,t.FullName
,DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, dt), 0) as DateBin

from (
    select
    case 
       when CoatingChamberStates.Name in 
              ('run_parts','running_parts') 
              then 'RUNNING'
       when CoatingChamberStates.Name in 
              ('idle', 'idle_resources', 'idle_waiting_parts', 'idle_waiting_analysis','idle_complete', 'idle_abort','idle_error')
              then 'IDLE'
       when CoatingChamberStates.Name in 
              ('running', 'unknown', 'error_deposition', 'maintenance_general', 
                     'running_warmup', 'running_centering','running_test_shot', 'running_other', 'maintenance_technical_problems',
                     'wait_start', 'warm_up', 'run_warm_up', 'run_center','run_test','maintenance_problem',
                     'pump_down','run_other','offline','run_test')
              then 'WASTE'
       else 'WASTE'
    end as Name 
    ,c.Startdt as Startdt
    ,c.Lastdt as Lastdt
    ,c.IntervalMin
    ,CoatingChambers.FullName
    ,dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, Startdt), 0) as DateBin
    from [reo].[dbo].CoatingChamberStateLogs as c
      inner join CoatingChamberStates 
        on c.CoatingChamberStatesid = CoatingChamberStates.CoatingChamberStatesid
      inner join CoatingChambers 
        on c.CoatingChambersid = CoatingChambers.CoatingChambersid
    where c.Startdt >= STARDTZ
      and c.Lastdt <= LASTDTZ
    ) as t
    join dates d 
      on d.dt >= cast(t.Startdt as date) 
     and d.dt<=cast(t.Lastdt as date)
  group by DateBin, Startdt, dt, Lastdt, FullName, t.Name

) as foo
group by Name, DateBin
```

Comment: prefix user variables with `@` so `declare @STARDTZ as datetime2` and so on.

Comment: @AlexMartin then why are you declaring them?. Also, they might not be `user variables`, but they are variables

Comment: I got it now, thanks for your comments! I do need the at symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're declaring `STARDTZ` and `LASTDTZ` as local variables, am I right?

you're using, as the error pointed out, the wrong syntax.

```
DECLARE @STARDTZ datetime2
SET @STARDTZ = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @STARTDT), 0)
```

you must define the type with space. In SQL, `as` would call for an alias, which is not the case.

Though it seems that SSRS doesn't work well with local variables.. maybe you should consider using the `Params functionality` , getting the value there and using your `Param` in the query.

I hope I've helped!
Regards,
Pedro S.

Comment: SSRS doesn't really have an issue with local variables

Comment: @lamak ok, then it should fix the problem! Thanks for the correction! I read somewhere that there were problems (i never tried using it like this on SSRS), so I thought it was best leaving that remark!